# Trying to solve a slicing question without the slicing feature

Tags: python, list, indexing, slice

The question is: Write a function called middle that takes a list and returns a new list that contains all but the first and last elements.

```
def middle(k):
    new_number = []
    for i in k:
        if k[0]!= k and k[-1] != k:
            new_number.append(i)
        else:
            return []

numbers = [0,1,2,3,4]
print(middle(numbers))
```

I'm using python, why am I not getting an output? Btw I know slicing exists but i want to know how to do it without it.

Comment: Where do you return new number?

Comment: Why are you returning inside the loop? You'll return an empty list as soon as you encounter a number that isn't the same as the first or last element.

Comment: Isnt it in print(middle(numbers))

Comment: I think when the question says "all but the first and last elements", they mean mean all but the first and last indexes, not elements that aren't equal to those 2 elements.

Comment: @Coolcoder No, because the function never does `return new_number`

Answer (score 0):

The condition in your if statement is checking if k[0] is not equal to the entire list k and if k[-1] is not equal to the entire list k.

You should check if i (each element in the list) is not equal to the first and last elements.

```
def middle(k):
  new_number = []
  for i in range(1, len(k)-1):
      new_number.append(k[i])
  return new_number

numbers = [0, 1, 0, 3, 4]
print(middle(numbers))
```

Output:

```
[1, 0, 3]
```

Comment: lmao im so dumb i put the value k != k[0]. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Mark. The modified function iterates through the elements starting from the second element (k[1]) up to the second-to-last element (k[len(k)-2]), effectively excluding the first and last elements from the result.

Comment: @Coolcoder, Hope so this is what you want !

Answer (score 0):

The check if k[0]!= k and k[-1] != k: will always be false.
The return []inside the loop will terminate on the first iteration.

```
def middle(k):
    new_number = []
    n = len(k)
    
    if n <= 2:
        # 2 or fewer elements will have no middle
        return new_number

    for i in range(1, n-1):
        new_number.append(k[i])

    return new_number

numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
print(middle(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to slice the input list then:

```
def middle(k):
    return [k[i] for i in range(1, len(k)-1)]
```

This will return a new list omitting the first and last elements from the input list

Answer (score 0):

What I observed from your code is when you mention `for i in k:`: Though you have mentioned 'i' here towards index, here 'i' will be considered as the element itself and not the index of the element. To iterate through index, the syntax is:

```
#if you have both start_index and end_index:
for i in range(start_index, end_index+1)
#if start_index is 0:
for i in range(end_index+1):
```

2. if a function has an output,the function should return output with command `return output`. What you learn as print command is meant for checking the output of any steps anywhere in between the program.
3. Here as it is mentioned clearly that the first and last element should not be present in the output, you can directly iterate with `for i in range(start_index, end_index+1)`. And there is no need of  `if` statement. So the solution can be any of the following:

   #method-1
   def middle(k):
   lst = []
   for i in range(1, len(k)-1):
   lst.append(k[i])
   return lst

   numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
   r = middle(numbers)
   print(r)  #output :[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: _"Any function should have a return value"_: not necessary. _This_ function should return a value because that's the requirement.

Comment: _"print command is meant for checking the output anywhere in between the program"_: the print function is used to print something to the console. You can _use it_ to check values if variables in the program, but that's not it's only purpose

Comment: Yes, I know that. Many beginners think that print is something similar to returning some value. I tried to mention that.

Comment: In method 1, don't call your variable `list` (it doesn't matter here because the variable's scope ends as soon as you exit the function, but it's a bad habit to redefine built-in functions and classes by using them as a variable name

Comment: And method 2 is explicitly what OP asked to avoid.

Comment: Actually, i roughly typed as op, then replaced all with l'ist'. But directly in the answer. So, this mistake occured. Now, I corrected.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's directly answer the question:

> Why am I not getting an output?

You don't get an output as you attempt to establish `new_number` but never actually return it. So, let's do that:

```py
def middle(k):
    new_number = []
    for i in k:
        if k[0]!= k and k[-1] != k:
            new_number.append(i)
        else:
            return []
    return new_number
```

That gives us "something" back but not the right something. Your current solution seems to muddle the concept of list index and the value of the list at a given index. `k[0]!= k` is (almost) always going to be `True` as the first item in a list is rarely going to equal the list itself. Similarly for the test of `k[-1] != k`. You likely wanted to do those tests against `i` rather than `k`. Additionally, when you do encounter the first or the last item in the list, you don't want to return an empty list `return []` you just wnat to ignore it so let's also take that out.

```py
def middle(k):
    new_number = []
    for i in k:
        if k[0] != i and k[-1] != i:
            new_number.append(i)
    return new_number
```

Now we are getting someplace and technically this gives you a valid answer (becuase all the items in the list are distinct with respect to the values of the first and last items). However, we really want to just positionally ignore the first and last items by index and really don't want to do any filtering with respect to their values. To take the values and the indexes of list items into account, let's use `enumerate()`. I know many have used `range()` and that clearly works but in the spirit of where you started, I think `enumerate()` is a better match.

```py
def middle(data):
    new_numbers = []
    for index, value in enumerate(data):
        if index in [0, len(data)-1]:
            continue
        new_numbers.append(value)
    return new_numbers
```

Now we are getting the right values and not just based on the coincidence that the values of the first and last items in the list are not repeated.

Having this last attempt squared away, we can refine it via a comprehension. They often clean things up nicely.

```
def middle(data):
    return [
        value
        for index, value
        in enumerate(data)
        if index not in [0, len(data)-1]
    ]
```